# How to convert ₹22000 string to float in python

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scrap.py", line 13, in 
converted_price=float(price[:5])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '₹\xa022,'

Comment: Is this some curreny symbol?

Comment: yes, Indian currency.

Comment: It appears you also have a non-breaking space after the rupee character (`\xa0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to filter out all of the characters that aren't part of a floating point number since the [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) function only allows certain characters.

You could use a [regular expression (regex)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to find all of the characters that are allowed in a floating point number. For example, to find all of the digits, minuses, pluses and dots:

```
float_regex = re.compile(r'[-.+\d]+')
```

Find all of these characters in the input string and join them together:

```
clean_input = ''.join(float_regex.findall(input_string))
```

And only then convert to a float.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> float_regex = re.compile(r'[-.+\d]+')
>>> input_string = '₹\xa022,'
>>> clean_input = ''.join(float_regex.findall(input_string))
>>> float(clean_input)
22.0
```

Comment: @Jan thank you for your correction. I wasn't aware that metacharacters aren't active inside classes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
dirty = "₹22000.83"

try:
    cleaned = float("".join(char for char in dirty if
                            char in ["-", "."] or char.isdigit()))
    print(cleaned)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Which yields

```
22000.83
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> converted_price = float(price[1:])
>>> converted_price
22000.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is there any way where I can omit the nonbreaking space? The output is converted_price=float(price[1:])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\xa022,280.00'

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question. What do you mean by nonbreaking space? what is your expected output?